# Finding column based on header then formatting rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to build a loop that searches through headers and finds a contained value, In this case, "Avg". If the value is found it will work down the column and apply a format based on a comparison to another column. I am trying to convert my cell variable in the For loop (Z) into a column address so I can use to control my ws.Cells() value in the next loop.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!!!!

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Z As Range
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

For Each Z In Range("I1:BM1").Cells
    If InStr(1, Z.Value, "Avg") Then

        For i = 2 To lastRow 'loop from row 2 to last
            If ws.Cells(i, 8) - ws.Cells(i, Z) < 0 Then 
                ws.Cells(i, Z).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next Z
End Sub
```

Comment: `ws.Cells(i, Z.Column)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Find Header and Format Cells

[image]

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:    In a column range specified by its header,
'             highlights the cells matching a condition.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub HighlightBelowAverages()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Highlight Below-Averages"
    Const COMPARE_COLUMN As String = "H"
    Const AVG_SEARCH_COLUMNS As String = "I:BM"
    Const AVG_COLUMN_HEADER As String = "Avg"
    Const AVG_COLOR_INDEX As Long = 4 ' Bright Green

    ' Reference the Search range.

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim srg As Range
    ' It is NOT assumed that the used range starts in row '1'.
    Set srg = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Range(AVG_SEARCH_COLUMNS))
    
    If srg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The Average search columns '" & AVG_SEARCH_COLUMNS _
            & "' are not part of the used range.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Find the Average header cell.
    
    Dim ahCell As Range
    With srg
        Set ahCell = .Find(AVG_COLUMN_HEADER, _
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByRows)
    End With
    
    If ahCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Header '" & AVG_COLUMN_HEADER & "' not found.", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the Average (single-column) range.
    
    Dim afCell As Range: Set afCell = ahCell.Offset(1)
    Dim alCell As Range
    Set alCell = Intersect(srg.Rows(srg.Rows.Count), ws.Columns(ahCell.Column))
    
    ' It IS assumed that the data has one row of headers.
    If afCell.Row > alCell.Row Then
        MsgBox "No data found.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim arg As Range: Set arg = ws.Range(afCell, alCell)
    
    ' Reference the Compare (single-column) range.
    
    Dim crg As Range
    ' It is NOT assumed that the used range starts in column 'A'.
    Set crg = Intersect(arg.EntireRow, ws.Columns(COMPARE_COLUMN))
    
    ' Highlight the cells.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    arg.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
     
    Dim aCell As Range, cCell As Range, r As Long
     
    For Each aCell In arg.Cells
        r = r + 1
        Set cCell = crg.Cells(r)
        If cCell.Value < aCell.Value Then ' Compare is less than Average
            aCell.Interior.ColorIndex = AVG_COLOR_INDEX
        End If
    Next aCell
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Below-averages highlighted.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Works Great, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear to me what you want - but from the title it appears you want to get the column number based on the header text? If so, this will do that:

```
 Private Function GetColumn(headerName As String) As Integer

    Dim col As Integer
    GetColumn = 0
    For col = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Value = headerName Then
            GetColumn = col
            Exit For
        End If
    Next col

End Function
```